# Did time have a beginning?

Tags: cosmology, time, big-bang

Did time have a beginning in the current scientific consensus? Or has it existed forever?

Comment: [Chronology of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe): “It is generally considered meaningless or unclear whether time existed before this chronology.”

Comment: Forever means for all time, so your second question is asking if time has existed for all time, which is like asking if position exists everywhere.